# Stopping Spark jar getting created in work folder

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running spark-kafka streaming application on standalone cluster.

Application jar is being copied to folder 'work' where the stdout and stderr files were being written. The jar is being copied to all the nodes that are being used and never getting deleted after killing of the application..

Can anyone advise me how to get rid of this jar after finishing the application run? Is there any parameter to prevent this jar from being copied.?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone advise me how to get rid of this jar after finishing the
>   application run?

Yes, [Spark has a cleanup mechanism](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) you can enable in each of the Worker nodes via the flag `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`:

> Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that
>   this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently. Only the
>   directories of stopped applications are cleaned up.

There are other properties for tuning the applications cleanup time:

- `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`: Controls the interval, in seconds, at which the worker cleans up old application work dirs on the local machine.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl`: The number of seconds to retain application work directories on each worker. This is a Time To Live and should depend on the amount of available disk space you have. Application logs and jars are downloaded to each application work dir. Over time, the work dirs can quickly fill up disk space, especially if you run jobs very frequently.

> Is there any parameter to prevent this jar from being copied?

No, this JAR is essential. It contains the code necessary to run your application. Otherwise, how will your worker nodes execute the code created in your graph? You must have this code available to all worker in the cluster, and Spark distributes it on your behalf to allow that.

Comment: The flag seems to work only when the application stops. But what about the application that does not stop like the spark-Kafka streaming application. ?